# Autocomplete problem with two identical "values"

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hash, autocomplete

I'm using the JQuery Autocomplete plugin, with l[ocal data stored in a array](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions):

```
data = [city1, city2, city3, city1]
```

Once the user selects the data element, for example `city 1`, I store it in `user_input`. I use the user input to read a hash that contains city, state zip, and name. The script displays each element of the hash on screen when the user hits enter. This also works great:

```
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
          var user_input =  $("input#example").val()

            $.each(personinfo,function(key,value){
                if(value['city']== user_input){
                    $('#city').empty().append(value['city']);
                    $('#state').empty().append(value['state']);
                    $('#zip').empty().append(value['zip']);
                    $('#name').empty().append(value['name']);
                }
})
```

The problem arises when there are two identical keys. For instance, say a name `"John Doe"` and `"Jane Doe"`, live in the same city: `city1`. Therefore `city1` appears twice in the data array, as you see above.

`data` is defined in this method:

```
  var data = new Array();
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $.each(personinfo,function(key,value){
    myarray.push(value['city'])
   });
  });
```

**How can I differentiate amongst city1 and city1 in the above array within the keypress function?**

The personinfo map object:

```
{"address":"07288 Albertha Station","city":"Littelside","created_at":"2011-05-25T19:24:51Z","id":1,"name":"Jane Doe","state":"Missouri","updated_at":"2011-05-26T21:25:54Z","zip":"75475-9938"},{OBJECT 2}, {OBJECT 3}, ....
```

Comment: The solution is to not use the city as the differentiator. What's the `key` in your `personinfo` map?

Comment: I've included the Hash object I am parsing.

Comment: Wait, this isn't making any sense. You want to select among city1,city2, city, and city1.  What's the real problem? Why do you want to differentiate between city1 and city1 (which are not distinbguishable)?  Can you illustrate the problem on jsbin.com ?

Comment: I can't get it to work on jsbin bc I rely on the autocomplete plugin. This is a simple problem really. When you select city1 in two seperate instances, you get the same result. Even if for example city1 is Springfield. Could be Springfield CA or NY - the code above always returns the same result, NY.

Comment: data is an array of possibilities, that is used as data for the autocomplete plugin (see link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments suggest, it's impossible to fix a problem with identical keys: the only way to fix it is to use non-identical keys :-)

I'd just combine city and state to make the key; seems like that should give you a unique keyset.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably late now, but I just had to fix this problem in a similar plugin and the best way of doing it is to pass additional reference with the lookup data.

As in `lookup = { data: ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'namex'], ref:[1,2,3,4] }`

So that when user selects second 'name2' the plugin will return selected 'name2' and ref 3.
It depends on a plugin if it supports this functionality, but even if it doesn't you should be able to modify it slighlty.